# Why am I getting this Error in Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell-2.0, monitoring

When I run this command:

```
$([Scriptblock]::Create((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://192.168.1.31/distrib/install/Add-RGMHost.ps1"))) -username admin -password admin
```

It says I need to put a value expression on the right of the operator "-"

I know its because of PS2 is there any solutions ?

```
ErrorID : ExpectedValueExpression
```

Comment: Download the file and execute from disk instead of trying to invoke it dynamically

Comment: Yeah that's a solution, but i need to put those parameters because the script generate a .yml to configure my device on my nagios

Comment: Have you tried executing in place by adding `&` in front?

Comment: Yeah that makes an Statement Error,

Comment: Please edit the full error text into your question, I can't see your screen :)